# Change NSTableView (NSScrollView) Frame Size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have a custom view which contains a `NSTableView`. By default, the `NSTableView` is contained inside of a `NSClipView` which is contained inside of a `NSScrollView`. The `NSScrollView` is bordered such that I can see the outline of the `NSTableView`, and the `NSTableView` is connected via an `IBOutlet` variable ("TableView") to its parent view controller. I want to change the size of the `NSTableView`, which as far as I can tell is done by changing the size of its enclosing `NSScrollView`.

I have tried the following commands, based on answers I have found here or elsewhere, but that don't work:

```
[[[self TableView] enclosingScrollView] setFrameSize:NSMakeSize([[self TableView] enclosingScrollView].bounds.size.width, 10)];

[[[self TableView] enclosingScrollView] setFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,[[self TableView] enclosingScrollView].bounds.size.width, 10)];

[[self TableView] setFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,[[self TableView] enclosingScrollView].bounds.size.width, 10)];
```

What is the proper command?

(OS X 11.1, XCode 7.1, Objective-C)

Comment: Are you using auto layout? Also, what do you really want to achieve, changing the size of the table view or the scroll view? They can be different sizes, which is precisely why a scroll view scrolls. For example, the table view could be big with only a relatively small part of it showing, and the user would scroll vertically and or horizontally to see more of it. Or, the table view could fit entirely within the scroll view, in which case it wouldn't scroll.

Comment: No, I am not using auto-layout. I always want both of them to be the same size, but I'm starting with the scroll view since it is bordered and I can visually tell if its size has changed.

Comment: Try breaking up your statement into its components and logging the result. For example: `NSTableView* tableView = [self TableView]; NSLog(@"table view %@", tableView); NSScrollView* scrollView = [tableView enclosingScrollView]; NSLog(@"scroll view %@", scrollView); ...`. Log the frame, try to set it, and log it again. Finally, when you say things "don't work", you need to explain exactly what you expected, exactly what actually happened, and how they differed.

Comment: Thanks Ken. By "don't work", I mean there is no visual change in the size of the scroll view, when I expected to see one.